# HazelCast Rest-Client Response Content -Type Configuration Problem

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have integrated the hazelcast mechanism in my project. I am able to store the the Data in the map by using the hazelcast instance reference. But I am feeling difficulty to set the response type for the rest client apis. 
I am getting the response as type of **Content-Type →application/binary** but the required format is **Content-Type:application/json**

I followed the documentation provided in:[HazelCast RestClient Documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3-RC1/manual/html/restclient.html)

I am storing the data by using the hazelcast instance in the below format:

Sample Format:

```
*Map<String, User> mymap = hazelcastinstance.getMap("testMap");
        User user = new User();
        mymap.put("mykey", user);*
```

Any one please help me with this issue

Thanks in advance

Url:
(Get Request)
http://localhost:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/testMap/mykey

[image: Hazelcast Configuration file]

Comment: That's an old doc link, to 3.3.  [3.11](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#rest-client)

Comment: @NeilStevenson even i changed to 3.12 beta-version also i am facing the same issue.can you please provide any configurations that i have to do it in my code.

Comment: @wildnez has beaten me to the answer here. You can request JSON content type in the response, but it doesn't mean you will get it, at least not in 3.12

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast currently stores data in binary form or in Java object. JSON support is coming out in 3.12, which is already in BETA. You can access 3.12-BETA here: https://hazelcast.org/download/

Unfortunately, REST would not be able to return JSON in 3.12. Perhaps, something can be added in one of the later versions, possibly 4.0.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable reply.As you mentioned i changed to 3.12 version but still i am not getting the json response. Can you please share any configurations that i have to do in my code to get the response as json instead  of binary format.

Comment: let me come back to you with an example

Comment: Apologies, I dug into the code and it seems REST returning JSON is not supported in 3.12 either. I edited my answer to reflect this finding. If you can look at other ways of reading data than REST then JSON in 3.12 is faster than many other document or JSON based NoSql databases out there.